# Take over Windows 7 PC with Remmina on Ubuntu 15.04 without locking screen

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote-desktop

I'm trying to connect to a Windows 7 PC by using Remmina on Ubuntu 15.04 using the Remote Desktop Protocol. Which works fine.

The only problem I'm encountering is that the Windows 7 PC, which I use as a status monitor for my servers, is that the screen is getting locked the moment I connect to the PC.

I've read that this is normal for Windows 7 to do because it can only handle one session at a time (or something like that). I was wondering if there is any solution for this so that I can:

1. (preferably) Take over the current session and use the session
   like  Teamviewer would do?
2. Open a new session in the background of the Windows 7 PC and use
   that session.

Both without locking the screen on the Windows 7 PC and both by still using Remmina. I prefer not installing additional software like Teamviewer ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible workarounds but each one has a different catch, so it might still not be possible to get you what you want.

If it is ok to connect to the Windows 7 PC, lock the screen and then unlock it after leaving you can use the command:

```
tscon.exe %sessionname% /dest:console
```

It will disconnect the RDP session and give it back to the console session. This is helpful if the Windows PC is some kind of public info display, but not if you want to work on the computer and have others watch what you are doing.

If you want to help other people with the remote session and require them to watch you could use "Windows Remote Assistance" instead, but would probably need to connect to a "proxy" windows computer first (unless there is linux support for it)
There you could run the command:

```
msra.exe /offerra
```

to be able to offer someone assistance. The downside with this method is additional lag by proxy and that it will not work unless there really is a person sitting in front of the Windows PC because you have to accept assistance.

Finally there is a possibility to get terminal server functionality in Windows 7 but it is questionable how this violates any licensing agreements with microsoft. So I would not recommend this in any enterprise environment and will not post direct links here because I don not know the policy for such things here but there should be a patch for termsrv.dll for Terminal Server functionality which you can surely find with google and afaik there is also an RDP Wrapper Library that enables the functionality without modifying the dll.
Downside here is that it's hard to say how the licenses are violated and whether these things work after a patch.